# Problem with the Definition of Inner Product Space.

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{C}.$ Then an inner product on V is defined to be a function $(,):V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ satisfying the following property:

1. Linearity in the first coordinate.
2. Conjugate-Symmetry.
3. Positivity: For all $x \in V$, if $x$ is nonzero then $(x,x)>0$.

My Questions:

1. If I  take $\mathbb{F}$ to be $\mathbb{C}$. Since it is not an ordered field,
   the idea of positivity does not make sense. But I find this definition
   everywhere. Am I missing something out?
2. Every Inner Product defined on $V$ (an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) is bilinear.
   Does every bilinear map $f: V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  give rise to an
   inner product on $V$?

Comment: Because of Property 2 one gets that $(x,x)\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The third condition should be: for every $x\in V$, $(x,x)\in[0,\infty)$. In particular, $(x,x)$ is always a *real* number.
2. No. If, say $f(x,x)$ is always equal to $0$; then $f$ is not an inner product. And, if $V=\Bbb R$ and $f(x,y)=-xy$, this $f$ is also not an inner product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added one more question to this. Can you please provide an answer to the added question?

Comment: @Saikat Done.${}$

Comment: By $f(x,x)=0$ always, you mean a bilinear map with this property. Correct? That is if we take  $f(x,y)=0$ always. Then this works well. Am I correct?

Comment: Conjugate-symmetry tells us that $(y,x) = \bar{(x,y)}$ for all $x,y \in V$. So, $(x,x) = \bar{(x,x)}$ for all $x \in V$. This shows that $(x,x)$ must be real. So we don't need to modify the third condition.

Comment: @Saikat Yes, that is correct.